# String Value stays the same in Class but is correct outside?

Tags: c#, variables, overriding

I'm writing a "Text Adventure Game" as a console application. When the game starts, I ask the player for his `PlayerName` and save it in a public variable. This will now be used to personalize a few parts of the story line, and is working flawlessly.

At some point, however, the player is asked if they would like to change their name. If they do, I get it from them and overwrite the existing string.

This is where the problem occurs: If I continue the story with the original array values (which were populated with the old `PlayerName` value), I see the old name is still there. But if I write out the value of the `PlayerName` variable itself, it has the new value.

If I get this right that means that in my array the value stays the same even if 
I overwrite the value of the variable from which it was originally created, but if I use the varibalbe itself in my code, it has the new value.

For Example:

- In the beginning the user enters the name `Mike`
- Now every string in my array which is created based on the value of this variable contains the correct value (`Mike`)
- Later they change the value to `Alex`
- If I print out the array strings which were created from the old value of the variable, it shows me the old value (`Mike`)
- But if I manually call `Console.Writeline` with the exact same `PlayerName` variable it has the new value (`Alex`)

My first attempt was to simply overwrite the existing Variable with:

```
Game.Playername = Console.ReadLine();
```

My second attempt was to create a method with a string input and the method will overwrite the variable:

```
Game.NameChange(Console.ReadLine());
```

Both of these result in the Array still containing the wrong (old) value even though the `PlayerName` field has the new value, which means the method is basically working but the array will not receive the new value.

Game flow stage "Name Change":

```
else if(Game.TempDec == "n")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Name:\n");
    Game.NameChange(Console.ReadLine());
    Dialoge.Narrator(StoryLine.Seq02[11]);
}
```

Method to change player's name:

```
public static void NameChange(string name)
{
    PlayerName = name;
}
```

String array definition:

```
public static string[] Seq02=
{
    "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
    "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
    "Your Name is " + Game.PlayerName + "...", //(Index 11)
    "...", "...",
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What I am missing?

Comment: this is a really long story, can you try to write the minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem? by the way it looks like you are expecting a variable inside the array to update, but once you use it inside that third element of the array the name will not change anymore.

Comment: `Seq02` is a field, not a method. It doesn't "recalculate" its value each time you call it, so changing the value of `Game.PlayerName` won't update the value of `Seq02`. What's unclear is how the value of this is getting set in the first place.

Comment: Please try to reduce the question to the specifics, with only the relevant details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing

```
public static string[] Sequence =
{
    "...",
    "Your Name is " + Game.PlayerName + "..."; //(Index 11)
    "..."
}
```

You are fixing inside Sequence[11] the value of the string. That value will not change if you change `PlayerName` because you are creating a new string with the value at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Even thought [Giulio Caccin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57580213/5632590) is correct, I would like to point out, that you can achieve specified behavior by using `string.Format()` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8). So everytime you want to print string with current player name you can use `string.Format(Seq02[11], Game.PlayerName)` where `Seq02[11] = "Your Name is {0} ..."` and `{0}` will be replaced by current player name. Also consider creating method that will insert player name to every string passed as argument, for example:

```
public string InsertPlayerName(string sentence){
   return string.Format(sentence, Game.PlayerName);
}
```

This method replaces every occurance of `{0}` in sentence argument with current player name.